# Properties of gas and mixtures

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, units, ideal-gas

Is specific heat at constant pressure for an ideal gas has unit always Joule/kg-K or can be Joule/kg-°C specifically for ideal gas only?

Answer (score 0):

The SI unit of the specific heat at constant pressure is Joule per Kelvin and kilogram, J/(K-kg). However, notice that an increment of the temperature of one degree Celsius is the same as an increment of one Kelvin, that is the same as joule per degree Celsius per kilogram (J/°C/kg)

Comment: As cp - cv =R where R is characteristic gas constant where R has always unit KJ/Kg-K where temperature is in Kelvin scale, so why cp and cv will have KJ-/Kg-°C unit also.

Comment: @LakhvirSingh the reason is that the specific heat is defined as the amount of heat required to change the temperature of 1 kg of mass by 1ºC. As I mentioned, its SI unit is J/(kg⋅K) or J/(kg⋅C) since the temperature change ($\Delta T$) is the same in units of Kelvin and degrees Celsius. However, the units for $R$ must be given always in terms of $K$ to avoid indeterminacy.